# how does adb find the emulator?

Tags: android, adb

After starting an emulator instance, I can use adb to control it. But i don't need to specify the listening port of the emulator. My question is how does them connect together? Use default port? or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It scans the even numbered ports starting at a specific range and attempts to connect. The emulator takes control of a port each.

Basically as said on http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html
In the network -port section it says

> The console port number must be an
>   even integer between 5554 and 5584,
>   inclusive. +1 must also be free
>   and will be reserved for ADB

Comment: Seems it has 2 ports, one is console port, the other is ADB port? What're the different purpose?

Comment: @Todd I do not know. That page may contain additional hints in any case